# Form submit button @ Transparent CSS Sprites

Tags: css, button, hover, submit, sprite

So im trying to style a submit button.  The background comes from a transparent png sprite file.
When all is said and done the button appears as a white box, and the sprite image isnt loaded.

`<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="" class="lp-submit"/>`

CSS

```
.lp-submit {
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:106px; 
    height:47px; 
    background:transparent url(images/bt_sprite.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.lp-submit:hover {
        background:transparent url(images/bt-sprite.png) no-repeat 0 25;
}
```

The image shows up if "transparent is removed from background:.  When its put back in its a white box again.

Comment: what's with the double slash in your path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the relative path to your image. CSS looks for relative paths from the folder it is in, not from the document root. And why there is to slashes?

Comment: Sorry there is no slashes in the code, i freetyped that in. lol - paths are all correct.  Also this is a wordpress project if that is important.

Answer (score 0):

The url needs to be a string. Try enclosing it in apostrophes or quotes (e.g., `url('images/bt_sprite.png');`). Also, you have a double-slash in the image's path. As the value of the url is a string, you do not need to (and should not) escape slashes.

Comment: Quotes are not necessary: http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/syndata.html#uri While quotes might help the parser overcome the real problem, they do not fix it. (My gut feeling is it might have to do with the double-slashes.)